# Lambda expression reduction example

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

How does one reduce the following lambda expression (λs.λq.s q q)(λq.q)q? In the first parenthesis, is q q an input to the expression (λs.λq.s) or is it a part of the expression (s q q)?

(λs.λq.s q q)(λq.q)q = (λq.qq)(λq.q)q = (λq.q)(λq.q)q = (λq.q)q = q

(λs.λq.s q q)(λq.q)q = (λq.(λq’.q’) q q)q = (λq.qq)q = qq

I get two different answers depending on how I see it. Which one is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it applies `q` to itself

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is to start reading the expression from left until
you arrive at a lambda. In your case `(λs.λq.s q q)`. Then continue
reading until you have found the next term -- the argument. In your
case `(λq.q)`. Then peel off the outer layer of the lambda and replace
the variable name with the argument. In your case `s` is replaced with
`(λq.q)`:

```
   (λs.λq.s q q) (λq.q) q
-> (λq.(λq.q) q q) q
```

Then repeat the process. Now the lambda is `(λq.(λq.q) q q)` and the
argument is `q`:

```
   (λq.(λq.q) q q) q
-> (λq.q) q q
```

The amount of q's is confusing, but the rules are trivial. Repeat the
process again:

```
   (λq.q) q q
-> q q
```

Now nothing more can be peeled off from the expression so you are
done. You can try it for yourself using the interactive interpreter on
[this
page](https://www.easycalculation.com/analytical/lambda-calculus.php).